# RegEx: Match a string containing unique groups in any order

Tags: regex

*Clarification: I need this regex to work in ECMAScript.*

I'd like to find a regex that would match:

- unique groups that occur a given amount of times (at least once, of course),
- in any order.

For simplicity, let's assume (for now) that each group is just one character.

Then, for 3 (unique) groups/characters with group sizes 1, 2 and 3 (these are the arbitrary parameters), we'd like to match:

- `aaabbc`
- `xxxyyz`
- `ababac`
- `ccbabc`

And the following should **not** match:

- `aaaaaa`
- `aaabbcc`
- `aabbcd`

Please see this link for more examples: https://regex101.com/r/zpNLHw/2

## Attempted solution

1. Use positive lookaheads combined with negative lookaheads to force the groups to be unique (first, capture the first group, then when capturing the second group, insert a negative lookahead just before to make sure the second group is different from the first group, etc.).
2. After the lookaheads, simply append `^.{total_number_of_characters}$` (in this case, `3 + 2 + 1 = 6`).

Resulting regex:

`(?=.*(.).*\1.*\1)(?=.*(?!\1)(.).*\2)(?=.*(?!\1|\2)(.))^.{6}$`

This attempted solution seems to work partially - it gives no false matches, but only a subset of the desired matches (please refer to the link above for details).

Correct matches:

- `aabccc`
- `aabbbc`
- `aaabbc`

Missed matches (should match but it doesn't):

- `abbccc`
- `abbbcc`
- `aaabcc`

Comment: Thought I'd throw in an alternative (possibly faster?) solution. Would [`^(?=.*(.).*\1.*\1)(?=.{6}$)(?:(.)\2*(*COMMIT)){3}.*$`](https://regex101.com/r/6q9vkt/1) work for you?

Comment: @JvdV Thanks, could you please elaborate why/how is this alternative faster?

Unfortunately, it won't help as I have to use the regex in ECMAScript that (as far as I can tell) doesn't support this syntax (I've added this requirement to the question now).

Comment: I think that one way to make it a bit faster in ECMAScript is to make the `.*` patterns lazy: `(?=.*?(.).*?\1.*?\1)(?=.*?(?!\1)(.).*?\2)(?=.*?(?!\1|\2)(.))^.{6}$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is that you need to check for the longer pattern first here. The reason is that once the lookaheads are atomic (at least, in the regex flavor you used), and once they find a match, they are never re-entered/re-evaluated by the regex engine when it tries to *backtrack*.

You will easily see what happens if you take `aaadcc` input as an example. The `^(?=.*(.).*\1.*\1)(?=.*(?!\1)(.))(?=.*(?!\1|\2)(.).*\3).{6}$` pattern checks for 3 identical chars first, then checks for a single char that is not equal to the captured char in Grpup 1 and then searches for two occurrences of a char other than those in Group 1 and 2. Have a look:

- The first lookahead is exited once the regex engine finds three `a`s and `a` is kept in the Group 1 buffer.
- The second lookahead works like this: `.*` matches the whole `aaadcc` string, then the negative lookahead is triggered and it passes, but `(.)` fails (as there is the end of string). So, the engine backtracks, and `(.)` matches and captures into Group 2 the `c` char.
- `(?=.*(?!\1|\2)(.).*\3)` now searches for a char that is not equal to `a` and `c` and is repeated at least two times - but there is just one `d` in  the string. **No re-evaluating will occur as lookaheads are atomic**, and the failure occurs.

**NOTE**: if you use *non-atomic* lookaheads (as those in PCRE2), you [will get the expected results](https://regex101.com/r/zpNLHw/3):

```php
^(?*.*(.).*\1.*\1)(?*.*(?!\1)(.))(?*.*(?!\1|\2)(.).*\3).{6}$
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. I had no idea about the concept of atomic operations in backtracking, I'd simply assumed that backtracking means, well, backtracking :)

Comment: @myke I mean, when backtracking, atomic parts are not re-evaluated, the result of lookaround check cannot be changed once it is "calculated". Backtracking and atomic are not equal notions.

Answer (score 0):

*This is a partial answer - it gives the regex we needed, but doesn't explain* why *the former attempt didn't work.*

It turns out that the order of specifying groups matters, though I don't really understand why (an explanation would be very much appreciated).

Originally, we had:

`(?=.*(.).*\1.*\1)(?=.*(?!\1)(.))(?=.*(?!\1|\2)(.).*\3)^.{6}$`,
i.e., groups specified in the order of `3, 1, 2`.

The regex that works is almost identical, except it uses the order of `3, 2, 1` (first group wants size 3, second group wants size 2, third group wants size 1):

`(?=.*(.).*\1.*\1)(?=.*(?!\1)(.).*\2)(?=.*(?!\1|\2)(.))^.{6}$`

Link to the working regex: https://regex101.com/r/wTHAma/1

Comment: I think you need to understand what [atomic](https://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) and [backtracking](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XDWK_tK2LUE) are.

Answer (score 0):

To get the items that are clustered only.
Still out of order clusters, but groups 1 , 3 , 5 contain the characters for a 1,2,3
char cluster. You can sort the match positions of groups 1,3,5 and get the
character order, for example `aaabbc` would be `3 2 1` number of characters in
match position order.

```
(?m)^(?:(?!\1|\3|\5)(?:(.)()|(.)\3()|(.)\5\5())){3}(?=\2\4\6)$
```

https://regex101.com/r/O8Pmgs/1

To get the non clustered character using lookaheads only,
this seemed to work for me. This one might not be able to get the order,
for example `bcbbac` would be `? ? ?` even though it will match correctly.

```
(?m)^(?=.*?(.).*?\1.*?\1)(?=.*?(?!\1)(.).*?\2)(?=.*?(?!\1|\2)(.)).{6}$
```

https://regex101.com/r/WdTw1u/1

Comment: This doesn't seem to be supported in ECMAScript.

Comment: @myke  JS ? You used Java for your demo. For this regex `(?m)^(?:(?!\1|\3|\5)(?:(.)()|(.)\3()|(.)\5\5())){3}(?=\2\4\6)$`   JS doesn't recognize capture states as flags. And `(?m)` which is the inline modifier is not part of its regex engine syntax. However this regex works as _flags_ in every other engine that supports back references. If you really need the grouping I could do something else in JS regex.